# How can I use a str.replace to take a value from a spinbox, and then replace an instance of that value in a text file?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using the re module of python to find all instances of 2 patterns in a text file. I have a spinbox which returns the value of that which has been selected.

```
from tkinter import *
import re

root = Tk()

num_names = open('numerical_sat_names.txt', 'r')
num_file = num_names.read()

satellite_TLE = open('TLE.txt', 'r')
TLE_file = satellite_TLE.read()
text = TLE_file

choice_var = tk.StringVar()    

class FindTLE(tk.Frame):
    pattern1 = r'(^.) (.....)(.) (........) (..)(............) (..........) (........) (........) (.) (....)(.$)'
    pattern2 = r'(^.) (.....) (........) (........) (.......) (........) (........) (...........)(.....)(.$)' 

    multiline1 = re.compile(pattern1, re.MULTILINE)
    multiline2 = re.compile(pattern2, re.MULTILINE)
    print ('Multiline   :')
    for match in multiline1.findall(text):
        print (' %r' % (match,))
    if not pattern1:
        raise TypeError('Bad line1 %s' % multiline1)
    print ('Multiline2   :')
    for match in multiline2.findall(text):
        print (' %r' % (match,))
    if not pattern2:
        raise TypeError('Bad line2 %s' % multiline2)

def TLE_selected():
    selected = str(choice_var.get())
    print('selected   :', selected)
    str.replace('.....U', selected[1])


TLE_spinbox=tk.Spinbox(textvariable=choice_var, values=num_file,
                    command=TLE_selected)
TLE_spinbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I would like the value of the spinbox to replace something within the text file; 'TLE.txt'; that is, (.....U). However I get the typeError:

```
    str.replace('.....U', selected[1])
TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The ('.....U') should correspond with part of 'pattern1' and follow the same structure as that which has been selected.

I am quite new to python and therefore would appreciate some guidance as to what I am doing wrong, and how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: you create class `FindTLE` without any method - it makes no sense - you can create function and get the same result.

Comment: `replace` can be used in two methods `"Hello".replace("H", "h")` which needs two arguments or `str.replace("Hello", "H', "h")` which needs 3 arguments - and here is your problem.

Comment: `choice_var` is `StringVar` and it always returns `string` so you don't need `str()`

Comment: as I sad your `str.replace()` expect 3 arguments `str.replace("Hello", "H', "h")`

Comment: where the first argument is the thing that is being replaced, the second, that which changes, and the third the proposed change?

Comment: first is oryginal text before changes, second is text which you are searching in this text, and third is text which you put in text. And it will return new string so you need `result = str.replace(...)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505207/how-to-use-str-replace-on-patterns-on-a-tle-and-then-find-a-match-from-the-tle. Having done some more work on this, it has run into a very strange problem that I can't figure out:  the part I want to replace with the value selected in the spinbox (selected1), is removed from the match found in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace can be used in two methods "Hello".replace("H", "h") which needs two arguments or str.replace("Hello", "H', "h") which needs 3 arguments - and here is your problem.

(Comment by furas)